# Get service from WebApplicationFactory<T> in ASP.NET Core integration tests

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to set up my tests using `WebApplicationFactory<T>` as detailed in 
[Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Before some of my tests I need to use a service configured in the real Startup class to set things up.
The problem I have is that I can't see a way to get a service from the factory.

I could get a service from `factory.Server` using `factory.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITheType>();` except that `factory.Server` is null until `factory.CreateClient();` has been called.

Is there any way that I am missing to get a service using the factory?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the startup used for the test be able to register and use the service? Show what you have so far in what you are trying to do

Comment: Or you could customize the factory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-webapplicationfactory

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. I need to get a service that's registered in the real Startup rather than the test Startup. I want to run a test using the fully configured application so I need to get the real service, call a couple of methods to setup some data, then run my test scenario. I need to be able to get this service in each test.

Comment: create a test startup that inherits from real startup. override configureservices, call base, build provider get service and perform setup

Comment: If I can see some code, I could probably provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot @Nkosi, I'll create a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for your offer @Nkosi. Apologies for not getting an example to you.

Comment: No worries. Glad to see you got a solution provided.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to create a ***scope*** from service provider to get necessary service:

```
using (var scope = AppFactory.Server.Host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDatabaseContext>();
}
```

Comment: if the `factory.Server` is `null`, consider calling `factory.CreateClient()` first!

Comment: For .NET 6 its just `AppFactory.Services.CreateScope()` - see Aleksei's answer.

Answer (score 22):

*Please pardon me. I know you ask for Net Core 2.1, but since v3.1+ people got here as well...*

My project uses Net Core 3.1. When I use `AppFactory.Server.Host.Services.CreateScope()` like Alexey Starchikov's suggestion, I encounter this error.

```
The TestServer constructor was not called with a IWebHostBuilder so IWebHost is not available.
```

Noted here, [by designs.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14424)

So I use the below approach. I put database seeding in the constructor of the test class. Note that, I do not have to call `factory.CreateClient()`. I create client variables in test methods as usual.

```
using (var scope = this.factory.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();

    // Seeding ...

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In APS.NET 6 and 7 I had to use `_factory.Services.CreateScope()`:

```cs
using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
var sender = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailSender>();
await sender.SendAsync("Hello");
```